# How to change the size of the text in a Pie Chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, size, pie-chart

I have a donut graphic but the texts are too small and I have not been able to make them bigger. it is a "PieChart" chart. I have my data segmented into A, B, C, D, E, F. I need to change text size, I am using a tablet size device and that is why the graph should look large, however the texts do not change size and I do not know how to achieve that my code is as follows:

```
  _RegZonesCircularTabletState createState() => _RegZonesCircularTabletState();
}
class GradesData {
  final String gradeSymbol;
  final int numberOfStudents;
  final charts.Color color;

  GradesData(this.gradeSymbol, this.numberOfStudents, this.color);
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
  

class _RegZonesCircularTabletState extends State<RegZonesCircularTablet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Región o Zona"),
      
      ),drawer: LateralMenu(),
      
      body: ListView(children: <Widget> [
      
    Container(
                height: 750,
                child:new charts.PieChart(
    _getSeriesData(),
    animate: true,
    defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
      arcWidth: 200,//ancho de la dona
      arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(),]
    ),
  ), 
            ),
      ],),
floatingActionButton:Container(
        height: 110.0,
        width: 110.0,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
        
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today,size: 50),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 5.0,
      ) ,) 
    );
  }
}



final data = [
  GradesData('A', 190,charts.MaterialPalette.indigo.shadeDefault),
  GradesData('B', 230,charts.MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault),
  GradesData('C', 150,charts.MaterialPalette.cyan.shadeDefault),
  GradesData('D', 73,charts.MaterialPalette.lime.shadeDefault),
  GradesData('E', 31,charts.MaterialPalette.teal.shadeDefault),
  GradesData('Fail', 13,charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shadeDefault),
];

_getSeriesData() {
  List<charts.Series<GradesData, String>> series = [
    charts.Series(
      id: "Grades",
      data: data,
      labelAccessorFn: (GradesData row, _) => '${row.gradeSymbol}: ${row.numberOfStudents}',
      domainFn:  (GradesData grades, _) => grades.gradeSymbol,
      measureFn: (GradesData grades, _) => grades.numberOfStudents,
      colorFn:   (GradesData grades, _) => grades.color,
    )
  ];
  return series;
}
```

[The chart is for tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ULlp.png)
Thanks, I'm a beginner, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code while creating `charts.Series`, we can manage the text style of the chart

```
charts.Series<MyModel, String>(
    //....
    outsideLabelStyleAccessorFn: (_, __) => const charts.TextStyleSpec(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: charts.MaterialPalette.black,
      fontFamily: 'MyFont'
    ),
    insideLabelStyleAccessorFn: (_, __) => const charts.TextStyleSpec(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
      fontFamily: 'MyFont'
    ),
);
```

And don't forget to add this in PieChart widget

```
defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
  arcRendererDecorators: [charts.ArcLabelDecorator()],
),
```